# Can on mouse over delay to show a gadget's "toolbar" be changed on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

When you hover your mouse over a gadget in Windows 7 a small toolbar appears on the right side with buttons for closing/moving/changing options. With gadgets that use mouse interaction this appearing/disappearing toolbar is an annoyance.

Is it possible to increase the delay before the toolbar is shown, or require some additional action to display it?